# Using Automapper in .NET Core 3.1 for response resolvers

Tags: c#, .net-core, migration, .net-core-3.1, automapper-2

I am trying to migrate from the full .NET framework to .NET Core 3.1.
In .NET Framework, we are using Automapper v2.2.1 for mapping, so in .NET Core I'm also using Automapper 2.2.1 version.

This line is in one of Mapper files for getting response:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<a, b>()
      .ForMember(dest => dest.prop, opt => opt.ResolveUsing<Resolver>().FromMember(src => src));
```

This is the `Resolver` file:

```
public class Resolver : ValueResolver <a, List<Service>>
{
    private readonly IParamUtil _paramUtil;
    private readonly MessageResources _messageResources;
    private readonly IParamValue _paramValue;
    private readonly  IProductDao _productDao;
        
    public Resolver(IParamUtil paramUtil, IParamValue paramValue, IProductDao productDao, MessageResources messageResources)
    {
        _paramUtil = paramUtil;
        _paramValue = paramValue;
        _productDao = productDao;
        _messageResources = messageResources;
    }
}
```

When debugging, I'm getting an exception like resolver file doesn't have a default constructor. If I use default constructor, I won't be getting the values of `paramUtil`, `paramValue`, etc...

Could anyone please help me with this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: How do you register automapper in you DI?

Comment: Do you really have to create a custom resolver?